# seperate a string to character stacks

Tags: string, stack

So I want to take a String input and store every character to a stack then I would pop the vowels from the String leaving only the consonants but I have no idea how. can someone guide me.

so far here's what i got

[image]

and this would be the output that i'm trying

[image]

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Scanner;
class stack
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Input a String: ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack();
        
        System.out.println();
         for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            {
                  char ch = str.charAt(i);
                  stack.add(str); 

                  
            }
         System.out.print("The stack is: " + stack);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why do you need a `stack` for such an operation? If you want to filter vowels and consonants you can simply iterate the string and store vowels/consonants separately.

In `stack` the problem you would face is, in `stack` you can only `peek` an element from the front-end, which would make you frustrating when you have a vowel after consonant because you can't remove the vowel in such cases.